# How to get ContentBytes property of an email attachment using office 365 rest api? I am using node.js below is the code which i am using

Tags: node.js, office365, office365-apps, outlook-restapi, office365api

```
outlookClient.me.folders.getFolder('Inbox').messages.getMessages().filter('IsRead eq false and HasAttachments eq true').fetchAll(10).then(function (result) {
result.forEach(function (message) {
    message.attachments.getAttachments().fetchAll(100).then(function (attachmentResult) {
        console.log('Message "' + message.subject + '" contains ' + attachmentResult.length + ' attachment(s)');
        attachmentResult.forEach(function (attachment) {
          console.log('*    "' + attachment.name + '" (' + attachment.size + ' KB)');

        });
    });
});
```

});

in above code i am able to get all the details of attachment except ContentBytes, please suggest me how can i get the ContentBytes of an attachment.

Comment: Did you try attachment.contentBytes?

Comment: @KaiLoh yes i tried with this also but it says "undefined".
Please suggest me what i can do.

Comment: @KaiLoh is there any alternate way to get ContentBytes ?

Answer (score 0):

The `contentBytes` property is only available to attachments of type `FileAttachment`. If it's an `ItemAttachment` that property will be undefined. Otherwise I believe it should work as `attachment.contentBytes`.